# 504 Gateway Timeout on apache tomcat 9

Tags: networking, server, tomcat9

I'm running tomcat 9 server. My request fails with 502 Gateway Timeout after 15mins of my request.any one know how to increase default time out in apache tomcat 9? or anyother reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

15 mins is usually a longer time. Any service/application should return the response at the earliest to its best. You should check the application if there are any issues, check the logs once.

I don't want to add this line, but still, if you want to increase the timeout, go to the server.xml file in the conf folder and increase the value of connectionTimeout property.

Comment: @Prkash Dontha Like you 15 mins is usually  longer time right. any way i need the solution for the 502 Gateway timeout. because  this is some migration related usecase. 15mins okay for my use case.

Comment: connectionTimeout property defines the maximum delay for the request URI to be received, not the maximum response delay. It is unrelated to this question as far as I understand it.